# Is it possible to have a complex nu in ParabolicCylinderD?

Tags: plotting, special-functions, complex

I'm trying to recreate a graph from a paper, and the function that I'm plotting involves three separate parabolic cylinder functions that all have a complex Nu value. After getting it all typed out, I end up with an empty plot. I've gone back to basics and have fiddled around with `ParabolicCylinderD`, and have found that I can plot it no problem with a real Nu, but as soon as I make Nu complex I end up with an empty plot. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I'll put in the test code I used while playing with the function to see if it worked, but it's just a case of using a complex input with the function to see if it works.

```
Plot[ParabolicCylinderD[2,p],{p,0,50}]
```

That one worked totally fine, got a good plot from it.

```
Plot[ParabolicCylinderD[2 I,p],{p,0,50}]
```

This one didn't work at all, got an empty plot as a result.

Comment: We cannot reproduce or work on the problem without the code for a minimal example.

Comment: I've adjusted the main question to include my tinkering example but it's literally just a case of putting a complex number in the nu value for the ParabolicCylinderD function

Comment: @PewtDmD  Plot will not show complex numbers. You need to take real Re and imaginary Im separately, or if you only care about the norm, then use Abs

Comment: Depending on your version of Mathematica, one or more of the following will work: `ReImPlot[ParabolicCylinderD[2 I, p], {p, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed["ReIm", {0.5, 0.5}]]` or 
`Plot[Evaluate@ReIm@ParabolicCylinderD[2 I, p], {p, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed[{Re, Im}, {0.5, 0.5}]]` or 
`Plot[Evaluate[#[ParabolicCylinderD[2 I, p]] & /@ {Re, Im}], {p, 0, 8}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Placed[{Re, Im}, {0.5, 0.5}]]`

Comment: Perhaps if you had added a link to the paper you speak of, it would be easier to see what the function to be plotted is supposed to be.

Comment: `Block[{f = ParabolicCylinderD[0.3 + 0.2 I, x + I*y]}, 
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{Re[f], Im[f]}], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  Mesh -> All]]`

Answer (score 1):

Yes certainly. If you have a fixed complex $\nu$ then use `ComplexPlot` not `Plot` like so:

```
ComplexPlot[ParabolicCylinderD[0.3 + 0.2 I, z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]
```

[image]

... or if you still want to use `Plot`, then take the real and imaginary parts separately:

```
Plot[{Re[ParabolicCylinderD[0.3 + 0.2 I, x]], 
  Im[ParabolicCylinderD[0.3 + 0.2 I, x]]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red], Directive[Blue]}]
```

[image]

For $\nu=2\mathbf{i}$ we have real and imaginary parts quickly decaying towards zero:

```
Plot[{
  Re[ParabolicCylinderD[2 I, x]],
  Im[ParabolicCylinderD[2 I, x]], 
  Abs[ParabolicCylinderD[2 I, x]]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red], Directive[Blue], Directive[Thick, Darker@Green]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Re", "Im", "Abs"}]
```

[image]

Comment: The result of `ComplexPlot3D[ParabolicCylinderD[0.3 + 0.2 I, z], {z, -1 - I, 1 + I}]` is more informative.

Comment: Also note you can do: `FunctionExpand[Abs[ParabolicCylinderD[2 I, x]]]`, `FunctionExpand[Re[ParabolicCylinderD[2 I, x]]]`, and `FunctionExpand[Im[ParabolicCylinderD[2 I, x]]]` to get forms in exponentials, cosines, and HermiteH functions.